# android ViewPager with Zoom ImageView

Tags: java, android

### i write ViewPager with pinch to zoom ImageView，Simply put Needing a way to disable paging when image is zoomed in and enable it when the original Scale image is shown.but when i handle onTouchEvent return false and then viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener not work how to fix it? Below is my code,thanks

```
   public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean enabled;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.enabled = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
    }
```

---

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            if(getScale() > 0.69){
                viewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
            }else{
                viewPager.setPagingEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help. I haven't tested it. So can't really say if it will work or not. 
If it worked then please let me know.

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

private boolean enabled;

public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.enabled = true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(null);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(null);
}

public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}}
```

Comment: it's not working get java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.MotionEvent.getAction()' on a null object reference

Comment: It was worth a try though.